# Find specific hexadecimals in file

Tags: c++

I am reading a hexadecimal file and I am looking for a specific set of hexadecimals and once I find that specific set, start storing the information.
The set I am trying to find is "AA 44 12 1C 1F 01". This set is a desired message identifier and in the file there are other messages that I dont want. I would like to find this set, and I know the information I want is 74 more characters long, then repeat the search and read process.

I know there is a built in std::fstream.peek(), but can I use it similar to std::string.find_first_of(" ")?

Comment: How long in average would be the files?

Comment: @NetVipeC unknown, could range from a few kb's to several mb's and contain an unknown number of undesired messages

Comment: @NetVipeC unknown, could range from a few kb's to several mb's and contain an unknown number of undesired messages

Comment: I recommend [mapped file](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/mapped_file.html) to load and [boost string algorithms](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/string_algo.html) to search.

Comment: Memory map it, and if performance is acceptable, brute-force-search. If you find the performance waining and want to ratchet up the throughput, invest in developing a [**memoization**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) algorithm to fit your needs.